# removing text inside of parentheses in sql then insert that text to different table?

Tags: sql-server

I have a column in MS-SQL that contain addresses the users added some additional information pertaining to the address in parentheses. sometimes it is at the end of the address sometimes it is in the middle. I need to remove that text is there a way to remove the text inside the parentheses and then insert it into another table?

for example the text would be

```
58795 North Test Drive (Main Office)
```

or it could look like this

```
450 South green Avenue (Green Ave. Office)  Suite 200
```

Comment: What should be returned for `One)two(three(((four)five)(`?

Comment: I haven't had to do to much with SQL scripts in a long time so I can't remember how to do it. I tried    

    SELECT REPLACE(STUFF(field,1,CHARINDEX('(',Field),''),')','')                            FROM table

 but the field is a text field so that won't work. I know I can use charindex and substrings but just don't remember how.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming exactly one open paren, and exactly one closing paren, then a simple solution exists. I use T1 for the original table name, and T2 for the new table.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

INSERT INTO T2
SELECT ID, SUBSTRING([Address], CHARINDEX('(', [Address]) + 1, CHARINDEX(')', [Address]) - CHARINDEX('(', [Address]) - 1)
FROM T1
WHERE CHARINDEX('(', [Address]) > 0
AND CHARINDEX(')', [Address]) > 0

UPDATE T1
SET [Address] = SUBSTRING([Address], 0, CHARINDEX('(', [Address]))
              + SUBSTRING([Address], CHARINDEX(')', [Address]) + 1, LEN([Address]))
```

--Check your results

```
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Comment: If not exist ( or )? I think you complete your correct query with a case statement

Comment: Edited to allow up to one each open and close parens.

Answer (score 1):

I Figured it out.

```
SELECT Replace(Stuff(CONVERT(VARCHAR (max), metavalue), 1, Charindex('(',    CONVERT(VARCHAR     (max), metavalue)), ''), ')', '')
FROM   metavalues mv
WHERE  mv.subfield = 3007
```