# Remove text within parenthesis in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex

I'm trying to remove parenthesis and text within it. 
Eg: Column1 has data and cleaned data should look like column2

```
Column1       Column2
HF(abcd)      HF
BP(234)       BP
ATRS (2354)   ATRS
AB(PS) SD(12) AB SD
```

I'm trying to use the below regex just to view the cleaned data, But I'm doing it wrong

> s/([^)]*)//

```
select Column1 from table where Column1 like '%s/\([^)]*\)//%'
```

What is the best possible solution for this

Comment: `^(.+?(?=\s*\(|$))`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [removing text inside of parentheses in sql then insert that text to different table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19415355/removing-text-inside-of-parentheses-in-sql-then-insert-that-text-to-different-ta)

Comment: By co-incidence, I was looking to do the same thing earlier today and looked up the answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

THIS ANSWERED THE ORIGINAL VERSION OF THE QUESTION.

What regular expression?  You just want everything before the `(`:

```
select left(column1, charindex('(', column1) - 1)
```

If you might not have the opening paren, you can do:

```
select left(column1, charindex('(', column1 + '(') - 1)
```

Comment: The second query Doesn't remove the '(' ...should I use a replace?

Comment: The functions I used were `left`, `right`, and `len`.

Comment: The char index doesn't work if the input is like 'AB(PS) SD(12)'. SQL's CharIndex gives AB only, I want to retain what is not in the parenthesis 'AB SD'

Comment: @shockwave . . . Changing the question after you have asked it is rude.  It can invalidate answers which in turn can attract downvotes.

Comment: @Gordon I never changed the question, it is the same as before word to word. I just added an additional use case in the table(Input - AB(PS) SD(12) 
 Output - AB SD)

Answer (score 7):

Try `Common Table Expression (CTE)` with `UNION` as below :

**Table Data :**

[image]

```
;WITH cte
AS (
    SELECT NAME AS [Column1]
        ,CASE 
            WHEN charindex('(', NAME) > 0
                AND charindex(')', NAME) > charindex('(', NAME)
                THEN stuff(NAME, charindex('(', NAME), charindex(')', NAME) - charindex('(', NAME) + 1, '')
            ELSE NAME
            END AS [Column2]
        ,0 AS [Level] FROM #TM

    UNION ALL

    SELECT [Column1]
        ,stuff([Column2], charindex('(', [Column2]), charindex(')', [Column2]) - charindex('(', [Column2]) + 1, '') AS [Column2]
        ,[Level] + 1 AS [Level]
    FROM cte
    WHERE charindex('(',[Column2]) > 0
    )
    ,cte1
AS (
    SELECT *
        ,row_number() OVER (
            PARTITION BY [Column1] ORDER BY [Level] DESC
            ) AS Rn
    FROM cte
    )
SELECT Column1, Column2
FROM cte1 where Rn = 1
```

**Result :**

[image]